# jpa named query not found

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0

I am migrating an ejb 2 application to ejb 3.1. Both technologies will have to coexist for a while. One of my entity beans looks like this:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "migracao_jsf")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "migracao_query", query = "select p from MigracaoJsf p")
    })
public class MigracaoJsf implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Column(name = "name")
    @Id
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

On the deployment logs in jboss 6.1 I can see that the entity was deployed.

```
 [AnnotationBinder] Binding entity from annotated class: myclass.MigracaoJsf
```

But I can't find the log for the query parsing. And when I try to call it I get a query not found exception. Why is the entity deployed correctly and the query not parsed?

Thanks

Kelly

Comment: Please add code where you search for query.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the query using the following code:

```
EntityManager em;
// em is created sonehow
TypedQuery<MigracaoJsf> q = em.createNamedQuery("migracao_query", MigracaoJsf.class);
```

Also it is common practice to prefix the named queries with the class name since query names must be unique. Thus a query to get an entity by its name should be named `Entity.GetByName`.